# How do observe touch events in core plot on ios?

Tags: ios, core-plot

I added this code to my graphViewController:

```
-(BOOL)pointingDeviceDownEvent:(id)event atPoint:(CGPoint)interactionPoint {
    NSLog(@"Touched.");
}
```

but it is not firing on touch. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `pointingDeviceDownEvent` sounds like something from Mac OSX, I don't recall it from IOS. I could easily be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm using the CPPlotSpaceDelegate protocol to receive touches on ios.

after setting the delegate for your defaultPlotSpace you'll get called on the following methods when touches are received

```
-(BOOL)plotSpace:(CPPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceUpEvent:(id)event atPoint:(CGPoint)point;

-(BOOL)plotSpace:(CPPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceCancelledEvent:(id)event;

-(BOOL)plotSpace:(CPPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceDownEvent:(id)event atPoint:(CGPoint)point;

-(BOOL)plotSpace:(CPPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceDraggedEvent:(id)event atPoint:(CGPoint)point;
```